# Topo To Raster tool stalling in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, anudem

I'm having the following problem -
An 8 mile by 4 mile set of 2 foot contours.
Whenever I start the topo to raster tool, I get a constant loop of the tool running.  And running, and running, and running, with no effect, even after letting the process run over 10 hours overnight.

Settings that I'm using are as follows:
Cell size 5
Extent same as input
Margin: 50
Drainage: Enforced
input data: contour
maximum number of iterations: 20
Roughness Penalty:
Discretisation error factor: 0
Vertical standard error: 0
Tolerance 1: 1
Tolerance 2: 100

Can you help?